# Toggle expand and collapse of Flex using JS and CSS transition

Tags: javascript, css, animation, flexbox

I am attempting to expand and collapse a div using CSS transitions. The div expands on click, and the transition is applied, however the transition is not applied on collapse. How do I apply a transition when the 'expand' class is removed and the div is returned to its previous state?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="collapse">
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var box = document.querySelector('.collapse')

box.addEventListener("click", function(){
  box.classList.toggle('expand')
})
```

CSS

```
.collapse {
 flex: 0 0 50%;
 max-width: 50%;
 padding: 30px;
 background-color: red;
 transition: flex 1000ms ease;
}

.expand {
  flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
  max-width: 66.66667%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: flex 1000ms ease;
}


.box-2 {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 30px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}


.container {
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

JSFiddle for reference - http://jsfiddle.net/gmezskwn/30/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gmezskwn/34/ - Added a transition for the max-width and that seem to have fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `max-width` from `.expand`

```
.collapse {
   flex: 0 0 50%;
   max-width: 66.6666%;
   padding: 30px;
   background-color: red;
   transition: flex 1000ms ease;
}

.expand {
   flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
   background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gmezskwn/41/